# Convert void to byte

Tags: c++

Please, help my.

```
class TLECustomControl
{
    private:
        ...
        HDC _hDC;
        HGLRC _hRC;
        void _stdcall MakeCurrent(void);
        void _stdcall GetSize(int* width, int* height);
    public:
        ...
        int Initialize(HWND handle);
};

void _stdcall TLECustomControl::MakeCurrent(void)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(this->_hDC, this->_hRC);
}

void _stdcall TLECustomControl::GetSize(int* width, int* height)
{
    this->MakeCurrent();
    int vPort[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vPort);
    *width = vPort[2];
    *height = vPort[3];
}

int TLECustomControl::Initialize(HWND handle)
{
    ...
    //Create a custom buffer
    this->_customBuffer = LE::CreateCustomBuffer((byte*)this->GetSize,(byte*)this->MakeCurrent);
}
```

//Error list

> Error 2   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void
>   (__stdcall TLECustomControl::* )(void)' to 'byte
>   *'    d:\leadwerks\projects\userwindow\LECustomControl.h

102 Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void

> (__stdcall TLECustomControl::* )(int *,int *)' to 'byte
>   *'    d:\leadwerks\projects\userwindow\LECustomControl.h  101

Comment: If `this->GetSize` is a method then you are not calling you need `()`.

Comment: You need to tell us more about this `LE::CreateCustomBuffer` function, like what it's prototype is like, and what data it expects as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's this line

```
this->_customBuffer = LE::CreateCustomBuffer((byte*)this->GetSize,(byte*)this->MakeCurrent);
```

The problem is that you pass *the member functions* as arguments, you don't actually *call* the `GetSize` or the `MakeCurrent` functions.

But it wouldn't work anyway, as neither of those functins return anything, but the arguments expected are of type `byte*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what to do in such cases?

Comment: @user2959203 You need to see that the `LE::CreateCustomBuffer` function wants, and pass that.